# Is there a way in either sql or web developer to all deleting say from a gridview all but the last row?

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a web portal set up where customers can add company contacts, etc to a sql database thru gridviews and detail views i created with microsoft Web Developer.  I need to have it set up, where although customers that have rights can edit and delete contact records, they cannot delete the last one.  There must be one left in the system.  I know this sounds like a strange request, but it is a needed one.  Is this something that can be done thru VB, SQL, or thru one of web developers objects such as the Details View?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "the last row"?  With the exception of some RDBMSs, databases in general tend not to care about the order of the rows in any particular table unless you tell them to (via an `order by` clause).

Comment: I am sorry.  It does not need to be the last row, i just need it set up so that one record remains in the table.  Whichever one that may be.

Comment: So you don't care which row remains, as long as there is at least one row in the table?

Comment: I would work on that subject line a bit if I were you. It's very difficult to understand.

Comment: You are veery right.  I will do that now.  And that is correct.  At least one row needs to remain in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a strange request, as I understand the need. The solution we employed is the actual default Admin account did not show up on the delete list, as it was "system generated". That may not be a retooling you can do.

What you can't do is use the automagic drag and drop crap and institute this type of functionality. You will have to either pair down the request to remove the last requested item, write a trigger on the database or write custom code to not delte the last item.

As an example of pairing down: with datasets, since they are disconnected, you can remove the last row prior to sending your delete request. With LINQ and EF, you have similar options to shaping the return data.

Then, if you desire to explicitly control your code (good), you can roll through the items and ensure the last one does not delete.

If you want to make this as "safe" as possible, you might consider a trigger on the table that checks if the delete is last administrator user for a particular organization and abort if so. Then the user might say "delete all" on the web, but the database protects them.

Comment: Lots of good suggestions.  Thank you.  I will take these suggestions and try to create the code i need.  I may try looking up how to create a trigger as you suggested.

Comment: Trigger is a bit more work and not as "user friendly", esp. if the user wants to delete all for some dumb reason. But, it adds a level of safety at the deepest level.